# Is "extend self" the same as "module_function"?

Tags: ruby, module

`extend self` and `module_function` are two ruby ways to make it so you can call a method on a module and also call it if you include that module.

Are there any differences between the end results of those ways?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`module_function` makes the given instance methods private, then duplicates and puts them into the module's metaclass as public methods. `extend self` adds all instance methods to the module's singleton, leaving their visibilities unchanged.

```
module M
  extend self

  def a; end

  private
  def b; end
end

module N
  def c; end

  private
  def d; end

  module_function :c, :d
end

class O
  include M
  include N
end

M.a
M.b  # NoMethodError: private method `b' called for M:Module
N.c
N.d
O.new.a
O.new.b  # NoMethodError: private method `b' called for O
O.new.c  # NoMethodError: private method `c' called for O
O.new.d  # NoMethodError: private method `d' called for O
```

Comment: yeah module_function class methods are public but instance methods are private

Comment: module_function "creates module functions for the named methods. These functions may be called with the module as a receiver, and also become available as instance methods to classes that mix in the module. Module functions are copies of the original, and so may be changed independently. The instance-method versions are made private. If used with no arguments, subsequently defined methods become module functions." source: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_module.html#Module.module_function