# Using extend self in module

Tags: ruby, module, include, extend, self

Before voting for closing due to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733124/ruby-extend-self) [duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353498/is-extend-self-the-same-as-module-function) I want to say that my question is really simple one (not asked in above mentioned questions).

There are two modules, one defines *module method* using `extend self`, another defines *mixin method*.

```
module A
  extend self
  def module_a_meth
    "Called module_a_meth"
  end
end

module B
  def module_b_meth
    "Called module_b_meth"
 end
end
```

There is a class, where I both `include` and `extend` these modules:

```
class Test
  include A
  extend A
  include B
  extend B
end
```

When we `include`ing module, its methods become class' instance methods, when `extend`ing - class methods.

**Question**:
it doesn't matter for class, if methods in module defined as *module* methods or *mixin* methods, right? I mean, when `include`d - EVERY method (either module methods or mixin methods) become **instance methods**, and when `extend`ed - either become **class methods**.

If I'm wrong - where is the difference?

```
obj = Test.new

puts obj.module_a_meth
puts obj.module_b_meth
puts Test.module_a_meth
puts Test.module_b_meth

#=> Called module_a_meth
#=> Called module_b_meth
#=> Called module_a_meth
#=> Called module_b_meth
```

### EDIT

Please start your answer with **Yes** or **No**, since my question implies this type of answer :).

Comment: grabbing some popcorn and waiting on Jorg ...

Comment: I dont really get the question. Can you state the question in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, regarding the actual question: **No** :).

Class (or any other object) cares how methods are defined in a module you're including. Basically, method's in a module you've described are defined as `mixin` methods. `extend self` doesn't redefine methods to be a module methods, but, basically, duplicates them to both contexts.

It's pretty much a question about how does `extend` work, it's just a tricky case.

First of all, think of `extend` as an `include` in object's singleton class context. Those two definitions are equal:

```
module SomeModule
  def hi
    'hi'
  end
end

class SomeClass
  extend SomeModule
end

class SomeClass
  class << self
    include SomeModule
  end
end
```

Given that, by using `extend self` in a module you're saying: Take all of the mixin methods I've defined and extend module's singleton class with them. This magic is a result of ruby's nature: an ability to re-open any definition. Here's how a verbose version of `extend self` would look like:

```
   module Module1
      def hi
        'hi'
      end
    end

    module Module1
      extend Module1 # which is self

      #### now "hi" is both here:
      # def hi; end
      #### and here:
      # class << self; def hi; end
    end

    Module1.hi #  => 'hi'
    class SomeClass; include Module1; end;
    SomeClass.new.hi # => 'hi'
```

__ EDIT __

Just a quick proof that object cares about how methods in a module are defined:

```
module SomeModule
  def self.hi
    'hi'
  end
end

object = 'some string'
class << object
  include SomeModule
end
object.hi # => NoMethodError: undefined method
```

Comment: ok, my problem was that I misunderstood the `extend self` concept - it doesn't convert each method defined in module into *module method*, but it makes any method both *mixin* method **and** *module* method.

Comment: Yes, `Module1.methods.include?(:hi)
 #=> true` (same as `Module1.singleton_class.instance_methods.include?(:hi)
 #=> true`), but `SomeClass.include Module1` does not make that method a class method of `SomeClass`: `SomeClass.hi #=> NoMethodError: undefined method 'hi' for SomeClass:Class`.

Comment: Audrey, that interpretation is not correct. `extend self` evaluates to `extend Test`, which which does not make reference to the module, so it obviously cannot `extend` the module on the class.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of whether you are using `extend` or `include` you are always copying over instance methods. The difference is where those instance methods live.

When you call `Class#include` you are "copying" all of the instance methods in the module to be instance methods in the class. It's similar to how inheritance work, and if you call `Class#ancestors` you'll see the module there.

When you call `Object#extend` you are copying all of the instance methods of the module to the object's singleton class. This is a class reserved just for this object instance that is created at runtime. This is how you get "class methods" (e.g. `MyClass.hello_world`); by adding them to the class's singleton. You can also do things like extend a particular object instance (e.g. `s = String.new; s.extend(SomeModule); s.hello_world`)

There are some other differences too. The context binding is different depending on whether you use `extend` or `include`. `extend` doesn't cause the module to show up in the ancestor chain while `include` does.

When trying to add both "class" and instance methods, one common pattern you'll see is doing things like this which uses the `included` callback to extend the base class with a `ClassMethods` module:

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def hello_world
    end
  end
end
```

`ActiveSupport::Concerns` also abstracts this pattern allowing you to add both instance and "class" methods in one call.

I personally prefer having modules only work with instance methods and using singleton methods (e.g. `def self.my_method`) to have scoped methods (sort of like how you would use private methods). This allows consumers to use either `extend` or `include` however they want and have it work as expected.

I'm not sure if that answers your question or not, but there's some info for you

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at this in steps.

```
module A
  puts "self = #{self}"
  extend self
  def module_a_meth
    "Called module_a_meth"
  end
end

class Test
end

Test.include A
  #-> self = Test

Test.instance_methods.include?(:module_a_meth)
  #=> true
Test.methods.include?(:module_a_meth)
  #=> false - no class method
```

So `include` includes `:module_a_meth` as an instance method. As `self` is `Test`, the line:

```
 extend self
```

is equivalent to:

```
 extend Test
```

which of course makes no reference to the module.  Now we `extend` and obtain the expected result:

```
Test.extend A
  #=> true 

Test.methods.include?(:module_a_meth)
  #=> true
```

`including` and `extend`ing `B` is normal:

```
module B
  def module_b_meth
    "Called module_b_meth"
 end
end

Test.include B
Test.instance_methods.include?(:module_b_meth)
  #=> true
Test.extend B
Test.methods.include?(:module_b_meth)
  #=> true
```

Comment: thanks for answer! My issue was with misunderstanding of `extend self` concept (as I commented under accepted answer). Upvote anyway for help!