# What does "self" mean in a module?

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between:

```
module Math
  def self.square(num)
    num**2
  end
end
puts Math.square(6)
```

and

```
module Math
  def square(num)
    num**2
  end
end
puts Math.square(6)
```

What is "self" in the first example? I'm only used to using self inside of a class, where self refers to the instance of the class.

Comment: The first defines a module function, here invoked as you have shown. You likely wouldn't `include` such modules. The second will raise an exception if invoked the same way, as it's an instance method. It's meant to be `include`d (mixed-into) a class.

Comment: When inside of a class, the `self` is the class, not the instance of a class. Only when inside of a method in a class, the `self` is the instance of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let’s see:

```
module Foo
  p self
end
# prints: Foo
```

So `self` is the module itself. This allows us to define methods directly on `Foo`, rather than instances of it:

```
module Foo
  def self.bar
    42
  end
end

Foo.bar  #=> 42

class A; include Foo; end
A.new.respond_to?(:bar)  #=> false
```

Note that this is not unique to Modules, and is the same for Classes. And since `self == Foo`, nothing is stopping us from doing:

```
def Foo.baz
  3.14
end

Foo.baz  #=> 3.14
```

Comment: What is the point, after all, of defining a method inside a module using self instead of without using self? In terms of your example, what is the point of including something like Foo into class A? Wouldn't we want method bar from Foo to be available in A?

Comment: So that you can call the method directly on the module itself—without including it into a class or instantiating that class. If you only have singleton methods in your module, there’s not much point in including it in a class, but I did it here for demonstration purposes. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2353498/211563).